# PHP: fopen path for `include`d script using Apache Document Root when full path is specified?

Tags: php, path, cgi, fopen, absolute

I am trying get an `include`d PHP script to write to a file, and the path is not resolving as I would like. Here's the scenario:

THe script that is running (the calling script) is web-accessible. To save me typing, say `http://example.com/script1.php` and the Apache document root of example.com absolute path is /home/jweinberger/com.example/

I have another script located (absolute path) at `/home/jweinberger/scripts/script2.php.`

script1.php contains an `include('/home/jweinberger/script2.php)` which works just fine.

script2.php tries to `fopen('/home/jweinberger/logs/script1.log')` which fails. The error message says that it is trying to open:

> /home/jweinberger/com.example/logs/script1.log//home/jweinberger/logs/script1.log

Clearly it is prepending the Apache document root of the calling script, which I don't want.

I have specified all paths absolutely (no relative paths at all). `safe_mode` is off, doc_root is empty and cgi.force_redirect is not set in php.ini. This is `PHP 5.2.17` (provided by my web host - I have no control over upgrading)

And, if it matters, script2.php successfully opens the correct file when called by a CLI script, just not when called by CGI.

Can anyone offer any advice or direction on what I can do to get script2.php to open the correct file successfully?

I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the Path starts with `/` It will point to the root Filesystem which is fine with CLI but CGI would understand it this way:

> /home/jweinberger/com.example/logs/script1.log//home/jweinberger/logs/script1.log

You should use the index `'DOCUMENT_ROOT'` from the `$_SERVER` array.

```
fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/jweinberger/logs/script1.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

meda gave me the clue that allowed me to find the answer.

My error was in the way I constructed the filename. I was prepending "/home/jweinberger/logs" to the current script name, which is wrong as the current script name is a full path.

When I used basename(current script name) instead, it worked fine.

Simple oversight. Hope it helps someone here